# Maximising a function under a constraint

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Let $$f(x,y,z) = 4x+2y+5z^2 \text{ and } A=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3} ; \, x^2+y^2+z^4 \leq 5 \}.$$ Find the maximum of $f$ on $A$.

My question is the following: How do I prove that the maximum must occur on the boundary of A, that is, when $x^2+y^2+z^4 = 5$?
It seems obvious enough, since if we had $x^2+y^2+z^4 < 5$, we could make $f(x,y,z)$ bigger by making $z$ bigger until we've hit the boundary of $A$. What would be a good formal way to prove this?

Comment: find $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ and see if there is extremum inside $A$ by setting $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=0$. If there's no extremum in $A$ then local max/min occurs on the boundary.

Comment: That is an acceptable argument. Suppose the condition $A$ is not bounding, then we can increase either variable by $\varepsilon$ and $f$ will also increase by $\sqrt \varepsilon$, which is in contradiction with the definition of the maximum.

Comment: ok so $f'(x,y,z) = (4,2,10z)$ which never becomes zero for any point in the interior of $A$?

Comment: @RasmusE I disagree, as this will only tell you that there is an extremum local inside A, not necessarily global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give a better answer than a comment. Your argument is valid, and it proves you have to be on the boundary.

Then, $z_{max}^2 = \sqrt{5-x^2-y^2}$, and $f(x,y,z_{max})=4x+2y +5\sqrt{5-x^2-y^2}$

Again you will find an other point at the frontier that maximizes that quantity (WA says it's (2,1))